# Overbrace/underbrace without extending brackets/parentheses

Tags: equations, brackets, braces

I'm using `\overbrace` to explain  a part of an equation, like this:

```
\begin{align}
a\left[\frac{d\cos y}{e} + \overbrace{\frac{b\sin x}{c}}^{\text{second bit}}\right]
\end{align}
```

But the overbrace increases the height of the brackets unnecessarily:

[image: Brackets extended unnecessarily]

Really, what I'd like is for the height of the brackets to be unrelated to the overbrace, like this:

[image: Brackets correct height]

Is this possible?

Comment: Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/108009/15925 help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
a\Bigl[\frac{d\cos y}{e} + \overbrace{\frac{b\sin x}{c}}^{\text{second bit}}\Bigr]
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: See section 6 of the AMS [Short Math Guide](ftp://ftp.ams.org/pub/tex/doc/amsmath/short-math-guide.pdf) for more on `Bigl` and family.

Comment: unfortunately, the space before the closing bracket is a bit wider than what would look best.

Comment: @barbarabeeton for you, a `\!`

Answer (score 4):

You can often literally [smash](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/98800/31839) the part which fiddles with your desired height :)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
a\left[\frac{d\cos y}{e} + \smash{\overbrace{\frac{b\sin x}{c}}^{\text{second bit}}}\right]
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

This comes closer to the posted intended output than David's answer, concerning the size of the brackets. `\smash` is a macro defined in both plain TeX and the LaTeX kernel. It reduces the height of its arguments to zero.

Comment: This looks interesting. Would you mind adding a bit of explanation, perhaps with a link to something to read about `smash`?

Comment: Added a little explanation. More details can also be found there -> http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171776

Comment: @LondonRob Note though that this completely hides the brace so it will over-print any text before the equation unless you add a `\vspace` to make some room.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle a *very* important consideration!