# How to align node anchors on text?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows, node-connections

I'm currently trying to realize an annotation on a TikZ plot, where I point out a limiting value (see picture below).
[image: Limiting value]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [stealth-,thin] (0,0.9)-- +(16pt,0pt) node[right,font=\footnotesize] 
            {Limiting value: $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0}\omega=0$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The problem that I have is that when I draw a line that connects to the node, my west anchor is not neatly centered to the text, but to the entire node.

> > Question: How can I get the alignement of my anchor in such a way that the arrow is nicely centered to the text rather than to the entire node?

Comment: While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

This is especially important for `tikz` as there are numerous libraries.

Comment: @PeterGrill Alright, I will remember this, thanks for the tip! The reason I did not do this was because the fact that I did not use any packages, but still it's better to give a complete question. So consider the question edited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to use `\smash` on the text which you don't want to affect the plcement of the node.  Alternatively, you could place the node in two steps:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [stealth-,thin] (0,0.9)-- +(16pt,0pt) node[right,font=\footnotesize] 
            {Limiting value: \smash{$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0}\omega=0$}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\medskip
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [stealth-,thin] (0,0.9)-- +(16pt,0pt) node[right,font=\footnotesize] (A) {Limiting value:};
    \node [anchor=west,font=\footnotesize, inner sep=0pt] at (A.east) {$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0}\omega=0$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, that completely solved it! :-) What does smash do exactly ?

Comment: `\smash` makes TeX think that the content in it takes up no vertical space. A good illustration is at [Which package defines \smash?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/171779/4301).  If it is still not clear you should post a new question.

Comment: That was all I needed to hear :). Perfect!