# What does \smash do, and where is it documented?

Tags: math-mode, vertical-alignment

I see several users in this forum talk about `\smash`. It is apparently defined in base TeX.

What does `\smash` do?

For future reference, is there online documentation where I could find this?

Comment: From the TeXbook: Plain TEX also provides `\smash{<subformula>}`, a macro that yields the same result as `{<subformula>}` but makes the height and depth zero.

Comment: Both of the existing answers leap into technical explanations of how the command is implemented, but neither explains what the result actually looks like on the page or why the command is useful. Based on the answers, I would expect that `\smash{aaa}bbb` would be typeset as bbb overstriking aaa, but in fact the output is exactly the same as if I just use `aaabbb` in the source code.

Comment: @BenCrowell egregs answer starts with " ... prints it as if its *height* and *depth* were zero", height and depth are not the width. But it into a \fbox to see the effect.

Comment: @BenCrowell Where did you get that idea? The width is not modified. In order to print text pretending it has zero width, there is `\makebox[0pt][l]{aaa}` (or `\rlap{aaa}`).

Answer (score 47, accepted):

As the name implies, `\smash` takes its contents and prints it as if its height and depth were zero.

The definition in LaTeX is carried over from the one in plain TeX, with a slight difference; I'll use the LaTeX one for ease of reference. The following refers to LaTeX 2018-12-01.

```
% latex.ltx, line 4494:
\def\smash{%
  \relax % \relax, in case this comes first in \halign
  \ifmmode
    \expandafter\mathpalette\expandafter\mathsm@sh
  \else
    \expandafter\makesm@sh
  \fi}
```

The macro distinguish if it is called in math mode or not. Note that, for efficiency, it doesn't read its argument at the outset. I'll assume the call is `\smash{abq}`. In math mode we get

```
\mathpalette\mathsm@sh{abq}
```

and we now need to look at `\mathsm@sh`:

```
% latex.ltx, line 4503:
\def\mathsm@sh#1#2{%
  \setbox\z@\hbox{$\m@th#1{#2}$}\finsm@sh}
```

According to the [working of `\mathpalette`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34393/4427), we get the equivalent of

```
\setbox\z@\hbox{$\m@th<current style>{abq}$}\fin@smash
```

If the call is in text mode, we have `\makesm@sh{abq}`. Now

```
% latex.ltx, line 4501:
\def\makesm@sh#1{%
  \setbox\z@\hbox{\color@begingroup#1\color@endgroup}\finsm@sh}
```

so we obtain

```
\setbox\z@\hbox{\color@begingroup abq\color@endgroup}\finsm@sh
```

In both cases TeX has set the contents of box 0; now `\finsm@sh` does its job

```
% latex.ltx, line 4505:
\def\finsm@sh{\ht\z@\z@ \dp\z@\z@ \leavevmode@ifvmode\box\z@}
```

This sets the height and depth of box 0 to 0pt and typesets the box after initiating horizontal mode.

When you load `amsmath` the definition is basically the same, with the difference that an optional argument is allowed, which can be either `t` or `b`. With `t` the last operation becomes only

```
\ht\z@\z@ \box\z@
```

so the depth is preserved; conversely, with `b` LaTeX only does

```
\dp\z@\z@ \box\z@
```

and the height is preserved. This is accomplished by the redefinition (referring to `amsmath.sty` release 2018-12-01)

```
% amsmath.sty, line 903:
\ifx\leavevmode@ifvmode\@undefined
\renewcommand{\smash}[1][tb]{%
  \def\mb@t{\ht}\def\mb@b{\dp}\def\mb@tb{\ht\z@\z@\dp}%
  \edef\finsm@sh{\csname mb@#1\endcsname\z@\z@\box\z@}%
  \ifmmode \@xp\mathpalette\@xp\mathsm@sh
  \else \@xp\makesm@sh
  \fi
}
\else
\renewcommand{\smash}[1][tb]{%
  \def\mb@t{\ht}\def\mb@b{\dp}\def\mb@tb{\ht\z@\z@\dp}%
  \edef\finsm@sh{\csname mb@#1\endcsname\z@\z@ \leavevmode@ifvmode\box\z@}%
  \ifmmode \@xp\mathpalette\@xp\mathsm@sh
  \else \@xp\makesm@sh
  \fi
}
\fi
```

You see that `\finsm@sh` is redefined each time to consist of the necessary bits.

The conditional definition of `\smash` in `amsmath.sty` is due to the fact that `\leavevmode@ifvmode` has been added to LaTeX starting from version 2018-12-01 to  initiate horizontal mode if found in vertical mode. In prior version of LaTeX this didn't happen, reflecting the same behavior as in plain TeX, where the definition is the same as in the LaTeX kernel, but without `\leavevmode@ifvmode`, which is defined in the LaTeX kernel by

```
% latex.ltx, line 1633:
\protected\def\leavevmode@ifvmode{\ifvmode\expandafter\indent\fi}
```

Answer (score 17):

`\smash` is a macro defined as

```
\relax \ifmmode \def \next {\mathpalette \mathsm@sh }\else \let \next \makesm@sh \fi \next
```

and `\mathsm@sh` is defined as:

```
\setbox \z@ \hbox {$\m@th #1{#2}$}\finsm@sh
```

and `finsm@sh` is defined as

```
ht \z@ \z@ \dp \z@ \z@ \box \z@
```

A simpler version of the command which makes what it does a bit more obvious is this one from *TeX by Topic*:

```
\def\smash#1{{\setbox0=\hbox{#1}\dp0=0pt \ht0=0pt \box0\relax}}
```

which basically takes some content and puts it into a box of 0 height and 0 depth.

It's documented in the TeXbook and also in TeX by Topic, which is included as part of the TeX Live documentation (`texdoc texbytopic` should bring it up.)

The actual macros in the LaTeX kernel can be found in the document `source2e.pdf` (also available through `texdoc`.)

Some packages such as `amsmath` redefine it.  See also

- [Which package defines \smash?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/171776/2693)

Answer (score 11):

This answer attempts to address @BenCrowell's desire for examples of how smash can affect the output.  As comments have indicated, it is height and depth, not width, that is affected by `\smash`. What this affects, therefore, is the vertical space allotted for the text, which could affect vertical placement of pre- and suc-ceding lines, the positions of super and supscripts (associated with the smashed material), as well as material stacked in conjunction with `\smash`ed text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document}

\noindent Affects placement of pre-\\
$\displaystyle\frac{Q}{Z}$ (vertical space widened to account)\\
and suc-ceeding material\\
$\displaystyle\smash{\frac{Q}{Z}}$ (vertical space not widened)\\
See what I mean?

\bigskip
Now let's look at super/subscript placement.
\[\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^a_b\]  
Compare if fraction is smashed:
\[\smash{\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)}^a_b\]  

Now for certain types of stacks:
\Shortstack{a b fg d e} versus \Shortstack{a b \smash{fg} d e}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Indeed. Outside of math mode, `\smash` is great for tweaking the size of text in a paragraph (using fontspec Scale) without spreading lines. The user is responsible for ensuring that the smashed text does not overlap something, unless the overlap is intentional.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, from [User’s Guide for the amsmath Package](http://www.ams.org/arc/tex/amsmath/amsldoc.pdf):

> The command \smash is used to typeset a subformula with an effective height and depth of zero, which is sometimes useful in adjusting the subformula’s position with respect to adjacent symbols.

> With the amsmath package \smash has optional arguments [t] and [b] because occasionally it is advantageous to be able to “smash” only the top or only the bottom of something while retaining the natural depth or height.

> For example, when adjacent radical symbols are
> unevenly sized or positioned because of differences in the height and depth of their contents, \smash can be employed to make them more consistent.

And they provide an example using `\smash[b]` under the square root symbol:

Without this option:

[image]

With it:

```
\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{\smash[b]{y}} + \sqrt{z}
```

[image]

The second radicand has reduced vertical limits for its bounding box.